# Fit table into one column for IEEE has formatting problem

Tags: tables, ieeetran

I am trying to let this table to fit in one column but something is wrong.

Below the **wrong behavior**, also as you see it extends to the other column which is an error:

[image]

Below the **desired behavior**:

[image]

Below the format I have so far:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs,chemformula}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,blindtext}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{seqsplit, collcell, ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\arraybackslash\collectcell\seqsplit}X<{\endcollectcell}}
\usepackage{lipsum}

// some paragraphs....


\begin{table}[H]
  \centering\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{>{\RaggedRight}X@{}ccc>{\RaggedRight}X@{}Y}
    \toprule
    Grouping & Dimensions & Rationale \\
    \midrule
 Analysis of publication data & Number of publications & Size of research ﬁeld \\
 {} & Time distribution of publications & Trends in the research ﬁeld \\
 {} & Most popular journals for publication & Journals where research is published \\
 {} & Most proliﬁc authors & Leading researchers \\
 {} & Geography of scholars & Setting of scholars \\
 {} & Distribution of keywords & no info \\
 {} & Social network analysis of keywords & Central Concepts \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

I have used the folloiwng [source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515047/fit-table-into-one-column-for-ieee) in order to achieve the type of table I wanted and that was useful but I have some formatting problems as shown in the picture.

Also came across [this other post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386802/how-to-fit-this-table-in-one-column-in-ieee-format) which was also useful to understand the concept I am looking for but not to solve the problem.

**RELATED QUESTION TO THE PRESENT QUESTION**
I have an additional question that is strictly related to this question: **How do I make the same table occupying both columns instead of only one column?**
I thought that because it is a simple variation of the question that I could also have it here. Please let me know if I need to write a separate question for that too.

Thanks for pointing in the right direction to find a solution.

Comment: Regarding your second question: Use the code from Zarko's answer below, replace `table` with `table*` and `\columnwidth` with `\linewidth` and you should end up with a table spanning both columns columns of text instead of one. The column widths will also adjust accordingly.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much @leandriis!

Comment: you need `table*` but your tabularx specification is weird you are specifying a 6 column table but apparently only using three columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{siunitx}    % v3!
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}%
                     \hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}L{0.8}L{1.1}L{1.1} @{}}
    \toprule
Grouping    &   Dimensions  &   Rationale \\
    \midrule
\multirow[t]{2}{=}{1. Analysis of publication data}   
    &   Number of publications
        &   Size of research ﬁeld \\
    &   Time distribution of publications
        &   Trends in the research ﬁeld \\
    &   Most popular journals for publication
        &   Journals where research is published \\
    &   Most proliﬁc authors
        &   Leading researchers \\
    &   Geography of scholars
        &   Setting of scholars \\
    &   Distribution of keywords
        &   no info \\
    &   Social network analysis of keywords
        & Central Concepts \\
    \addlinespace
\multirow[t]{2}{=}{2. Analysis of citation data}   
    &   Number of citations
        &   Central concepts \\
    &   Time distribution of citations
        &   Realtions between central concepts \\
    &   \dots
        &   \dots   \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

You have ill-defined table: in use are only three columns, but defined are six. Also cell formatting is to complicated. SE MWE, the code should be self-explanatory.

Comment: Yes the snippet of code is self-explanatory. Thank you very much for stopping by and help me solve this problem. I appreciate it!